# In JSP, how to increment value by 1 for each record?

Tags: html, jsp

I have a simple JSP page that retrieves records and display it like this:

[image: Screenshot]

I need to increment the No column so that it shows the appropriate number,i.e (1,2,3,4,5).

My code:

```
<table class="filesTbl">
    <tr>
        <th width="1%">
            Checkbox
        </th>
        <th width="1%">
             No
        </th>
        <th width="20%">
            File Name
        </th>
        <th width="50%">
            Unique URL
        </th>
        <th width="1%">
            Edit
        </th>
        <th width="1%">
            Copy
        </th>
        <th width="1%">
            Email
        </th>

    </tr>

<%
    //need to input logic to populate data on each row


    String[] split = request.getParameter("nodeID").split(",",0);
    for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++){

        long file=Long.parseLong(split[i]);

    List files = fileFacade.list_items(file);
    for (Iterator rstltr = files.iterator(); rstltr.hasNext();) {
        Fmedia fv = (Fmedia) rstltr.next();
        Node nd = nodeFacade.get(fv.getNodeid(), false);
       // Fmedia fm = fileFacade.get_file(fv.getNodeid());

        int count = 0;
        count++;




%>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="5%">
<!--Display Checkbox   -->
            <input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;
        </td>

        <td>
            <!--Display No   -->
            <%int counter=1;%>
            <%for(int j=1;j<=2;j++){
 ///////////logic to display goes here
            %>


            <%=counter%>
            <%counter++;%>


            <%}%>



        </td>
        <td width="28%">

            <!-- Display Filename   -->
            <%=nd.getNodedesc()%>
        </td>


    </tr>

    </tbody>


<%}}
%>








</table>
```

I tried using a for loop but it just prints the same value for each row and this column is already in an outer for loop so I am not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

```
 <%
   int count=0;//add this for counter

    String[] split = request.getParameter("nodeID").split(",",0);
    for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++){

        long file=Long.parseLong(split[i]);

    List files = fileFacade.list_items(file);
    for (Iterator rstltr = files.iterator(); rstltr.hasNext();) {
        Fmedia fv = (Fmedia) rstltr.next();
        Node nd = nodeFacade.get(fv.getNodeid(), false);
       // Fmedia fm = fileFacade.get_file(fv.getNodeid());

%>


        <td>
            <!--Display No   -->
        <%
         count=count+1;//adding by 1
        out.println(count);//printing count
           %>     

        </td>
```